# sass modules daesn't load on the build of Next js 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sass

i am using sass modules in next js 13 app
in 'npm run dev'  mode everything is fine but in the 'npm start' the styles are missing
i installed sass and nothing changed
should i do something with webpack?

```
{
  "name": "fake",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.3",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.0",
    "@mui/types": "^7.2.4",
    "@types/node": "20.5.0",
    "@types/react": "18.2.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "eslint": "8.47.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.16",
    "next": "13.4.16",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.1.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Assuming what you shared is the contents of `package.json`, *"i installed sass"* appears to be `false`. Run `npm i sass -D` (or `yarn add sass -D`, if you use `yarn`) in the root folder of your project.

Comment: i installed the sass and did the build process and nothing changed and uninstalled it again